# Google Appengine query returns nothing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a one record NDB called ProductList which includes the following values:

```
ProductList(key=Key('ProductList', '<0a304802-7263-455b-aa0f-e4f7a574d355>'),strVal=u'software', tx_code=u'category')
```

The problem is that when I run

```
query_rows = qm_models.ProductList.get(None, u'category', u'software')
```

where the get method is..

```
class ProductList(ndb.Model):
    tid = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    tx_code = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True) 
    strVal = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

    @classmethod
    def get(self, tid=None, tx_code=None, strVal=None, fetch_count=999):
        if tx_code and strVal:
            return self.query(self.tx_code == 'category', self.strVal == 
                   u'software').fetch(fetch_count)
```

the query returns nothing (ie. None).

What am I missing?
FYI. If I exclude `"self.strVal == u'software'"` from the return statement, the query properly returns the record shown at the top.
Also, I tried the query with or without the `u'(unicode)` in front of `'category'` and `'software'`. Neither worked.

Comment: On a style/python note, you shouldn't as a convention use `self` for class methods.  You are passed the class and not an instance of a class when calling classemthods.  Normally you would use `cls`

Comment: You don't normally need to specify `indexed=True` on StringProperty.  Had you marked those as `index=False` at some point, and then changed the model to explicitly include the index ?  If you have you need to re-put() the entity to update the index.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your response. What do you mean by "re-put()"? How do I do it?

Comment: Fetch each object, and then call `put()` then the object will be reindexed.

Comment: Thank you! The problem disappeared when I deleted all items in the entity and inserted the data again.